# How to filter a combobox which depends on the other combobox in a grid or form(netzke)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, combobox, netzke

The domain models: type1, type2, type3 and plant.

```
$ rails g model type1 name:string
$ rails g model type2 name:string
$ rails g model type3 type1:references type2:references name:string
$ rails g model plant type1:references type2:references type3:references name:string
```

In a plant's grid panel, there will be three combobox columns: type1, type2 and type3. Type3 depends on type1 and type2. How to filter type3 combobox when any one of type1 and type2 is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm new to Rails and Netzke, but this is how I would solve the problem.

First, if Type3 depends on Type1 and Type2, then only Type3 should be referenced in Plant.

So, instead of

```
rails g model plant type1:references type2:references type3:references name:string
```

use

```
rails g model plant type3:references name:string
```

You can always reference type1 and type2 by using Netzke's `__` (double underline) notation. This is my version of Plants grid. I do not allow inline editing, except for most trivial models.

```
class Plants < Netzke::Basepack::Grid
  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = 'Plant'
    c.persistence = true
    c.columns = [
      { name: :type3__type1__name, header: 'Type 1'},
      { name: :type3__type2__name, header: 'Type 2'},
      { name: :type3__name, header: 'Type 3'},
      { name: :name, header: 'Plant Name' }
    ]
    c.enable_edit_inline = false
    c.enable_add_inline = false
  end

  def preconfigure_record_window(c)
    super
    c.form_config.klass = PlantForm
  end
end
```

To connect the combo boxes you need to:

1. Define scope for type3 combo so that its data depends on type1 and type2 IDs.

   ```
   #Example scope definition
   scope: {type1_id: component_session[:type1_id],
           type2_id: component_session[:type2_id]}
   ```
2. Define listeners for type1 and type2 combos (see `js_configure` method). Listeners will detect any change in type1 and type2 and prepare type3 to refresh its data next time it gets selected.
3. Endpoints and session variables are used for IDs exchange.

   ```
   //JavaScript code
   //Definition of listener function for type1 combo
   var handleType1Change = function() {

     //Type3 value is no longer valid
     type3Combo.clearValue();

     //Setting lastQuer to null will force data refresh for type3 combo
     //next time it gets selected.
     type3Combo.lastQuery = null;

     //Call endpoint to define session variable with ID of type1 combo
     this.selectType1({type1_id: type1Combo.value});
   };

   #Ruby code
   #The endpoint is called from handleType1Chnage listener to
   #set session variable with selected ID in type1 combo.
   endpoint :select_type1 do |params, this|
     component_session[:type1_id] = params[:type1_id]
   end
   ```

This is my complete code for Plant form:

```
class PlantForm< Netzke::Basepack::Form
  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = 'Plant'
    c.title = 'Plant'
    c.items = [
      {
        field_label: 'Type1',
        xtype: :combo,
        store: Type1.select([:id, :name]).map { |x| [x.id, x.name] },
        id: 'type1Combo',
        #Sets the value for type1 in case change form is opened
        value: record && record.id ? record.type3.type1_id : nil
      },
      {
        field_label: 'Type2',
        xtype: :combo,
        store: Type2.select([:id, :name]).map { |x| [x.id, x.name] },
        id: 'type2Combo',
        #Sets the value for type2 in case change form is opened
        value: record && record.id ? record.type3.type2_id : nil
      },
      { 
        field_label: 'Type3', 
        name: :type3__name,
        id: 'type3Combo',
        data_store: {auto_load: false},
        scope: {type1_id: component_session[:type1_id],
                type2_id: component_session[:type2_id]}
      },
      { field_label: 'Name', name: :name }
    ]
  end

  js_configure do |c|
    c.init_component = <<-JS
      function() {
        this.callParent();

        var type1Combo = this.getComponent('type1Combo');
        var type2Combo = this.getComponent('type2Combo');
        var type3Combo = this.getComponent('type3Combo');

        var handleType1Change = function() {
          type3Combo.clearValue();
          type3Combo.lastQuery = null; //force data refresh in type3 combo
          this.selectType1({type1_id: type1Combo.value});
        };

        var handleType2Change = function() {
          type3Combo.clearValue();
          type3Combo.lastQuery = null;
          this.selectType2({type2_id: type2Combo.value});
        };

        type1Combo.addListener('select', handleType1Change, this);
        type2Combo.addListener('select', handleType2Change, this);
      }
    JS
  end

  endpoint :select_type1 do |params, this|
    component_session[:type1_id] = params[:type1_id]
  end

  endpoint :select_type2 do |params, this|
    component_session[:type2_id] = params[:type2_id]
  end

end
```

Comment: @Drazen, Can you explain how this kind of a form can be used for filtering records. I can raise a separate question if required.